# Ant Matcher for GET Parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ant

Using Java + SpringBoot, I'm trying to create and endpoint for confirming the user email.

The link I generated and sent was `/confirm-email?id=x&token=xyztetc`

However, due to the fact that only `/signup` is permitted to be accessed without a Bearer token, the link will always get a 403 response. I've tried to add `/confirm-email?{id:.+}&{token:.+}` for being permitted, but with no success.

I'm 100% sure that the regex isn't correctly written, but I can't find any relevant Ant pattern documentation to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ant uses the `.` to match any character, it uses `?`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've actually tried with "?" but no success. Ironically, the solution was to keep the URL like this '/confirm-email'

Comment: It seems the spring security ant pattern matcher ignores query strings. From the JavaDocs of AntPathRequestMatcher: `Matcher which compares a pre-defined ant-style pattern against the URL ( servletPath + pathInfo) of an HttpServletRequest. The query string of the URL is ignored...`

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow regex matchers, you must use `.regexMatchers()` instead of `.antMatchers()`.

See this class for more information:

```
org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher
```

It would be something like this in your case:

```
public class ServerSecurityAppConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    private static final String[] UNAUTHENTICATED_ROUTES = new String[] {
            "/confirm-email?{.+}&{.+}",
    };


    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers( UNAUTHENTICATED_ROUTES ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().access( myAppSecurityExpression );
    }
```